# aurelia-http-client connects to wrong address

Tags: xmlhttprequest, aurelia

I have a problem with the aurelia Http Client.
My api (http//localhost:3000/api/posts) works fine. The output of a get call (in postman or in the browser) is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "58a5f4f635c3ab643c74d97a",
    "text": "Foo",
    "name": "Fooo",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "58a5fcc32586d0683455f78d",
    "text": "Bar",
    "name": "Baar",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

This is my get call in the aurelia app:

```
getPosts(){
 return client.get('http//localhost:3000/api/posts','callback')
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data.response;
  })
}
```

[And this is the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJxdv.png)
As you can see in the image the response contains something with "Aurelia" but my api never touched aurelia so i think there is something wrong with the URL.

**Update1:**

The fix suggested by GManProgram (missing `:`) was the problem.

**Update2:**

I have changed to the client to the aurelia-fetch-client as GManProgram suggested.
[Here is the new output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgGcB.png)
I seems to put the address from the api behind its own address. Ho can I force it only to use the api address?

Comment: Sorry, I never saw your edits and it might be way too late not. The fetch client is good if all of your resources are at the same location with different endpoints (for example you have a both a post and comment route at localhost:3000). 

You can configure the fetch client to set a baseUrl to your desired location. Normally, I do the configuration in main.js and it looks something like

`httpClient.configure(config => { config.withBaseUrl('http:localhost:300/api/'); });`

Then making a web call is as simple as `httpClient.fetch('posts')`

Comment: Similarly, the aurelia-http-client (which is similar to the aurelia-fetch-client) can be configured similarly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first things first, in the example you posted, you are missing the `:` character after http in the URL.

If that doesn't fix it, and you are using the `HttpClient` from `aurelia-fetch-client`, then you may want to try using the .fetch method instead of the .get method

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/fetch-client/1.1.0/class/HttpClient

In your case, since it looks like you are expecting json, the typical fetch call would look like:

```
return this.httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => new CaseModel(response));
```

Where you can also import the `json` method from aurelia-fetch-client.

Otherwise, maybe the HttpClient has already been configured in the application with a base URL and it is screwing you up?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
return client.get('posts','callback')
```